# VB.NET + Crystal Report = True?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm making a VB.NET application that needs to generate a number of different reports. The customer is already using Crystal Report and is happy with that so the plan is to integrate with that.

What I basically want to do is:

- Manually create template(s) in
  crystal report
- User selects type of report in
  application
- User filters the data according to
  his wishes
- Crystal Report is opened with the
  relevant template and values from the
  application inserted
- User can then review the data, create
  PDFs and print the reports.

My questions are:

- Is this doable at all in a simple
  way(quite a low budget project)? Are
  there any good tutorials?
- I don't want Crystal Report to
  communicate directly with the
  database but a number of calculations
  needs to be done in the VB.NET code.
  Do I need to prepare the data in some
  special way?
- Can I include the Crystal Report
  templates inside the application and
  extract them when the report needs to
  be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio does come with Crystal Reports functionality "in the box" (and has done since Visual Studio.Net) - you can use that to create your Crystal Reports, which by default will be embedded as a resource, if included in a project. It is possible also to load external files as well, though.

It's probably worth taking a look at the samples that use the Crystal Report viewer, as they will show that most of what you're asking is covered...